# Как открыть модальное окно по клику на option внутри select?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Есть селектфилд:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Add to ...</option>
    <option value="cart">Cart</option>
    <option  data-divider="true" disabled>___________________</option>
    <option value="" ><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Create new list</a></option>
</select>
```

Код модального окна:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По выбору в выпадающем меню option'а c  модальное окно не всплывает,если же анхор расопложить отдельно,то всплывает.В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Нельзя просто взять и поместить ссылку в селект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте идентификатор `id` к элементу `select` и значение `value` к элементу `option` на нажатие которого Вы хотите навесить открытие модального окна. А потом в `JavaScript` сделайте обработку на изменение `select`. Ссылка `<a...` внутри элемента `option` не нужна - ее необходимо удалить. Далее рабочий пример открытия модалки при выборе определенного `option` из `select`:

```js
// небольшой JS на обработку смены выбранного элемента
$("#openmodal").on("change", function () {        
    if($(this).val() === 'openmodaloption'){
       $('#modal').modal('show');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<select id='openmodal'> <!-- тут добавим идентификатор -->
   <option value="" selected="selected">Add to ...</option>
   <option value="cart">Cart</option>
   <option data-divider="true" disabled>____</option>
   <option value="openmodaloption">Create new list</option> <!-- тут заполним value -->
</select>

<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да,проблема в этом.поправил.все работает,спасибо)